# Alternatives to byobu as a tmux distribution?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, byobu

Are there good alternatives for byobu as a tmux distribution?. Minimal, stable and that just works? or most tmux users just learn tmux specifics and configure it all by themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered on this question a while ago since `byobu` was getting huge and I didn't necessarily wanted all of it.

So it seems like tmux users in general are like vim/emacs ones, they tend to write quite personalized `~/.tmux.conf` files.

There is however a recent attempt to create a more general tmux plugin environment:

- [tpm](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm)
- [tmux-plugins](https://github.com/tmux-plugins)

Unfortunately it targets recent tmux versions (>=1.9). Since I'm stuck with tmux 1.6 on some systems (Ubuntu Precise), I've forked the most popular plugins on:

- [tundle](https://github.com/chilicuil/tundle)
- [tundle-plugins](https://github.com/chilicuil/tundle-plugins)

So those seem to be the current alternatives.